# Восстановление файлов проекта после повреждения. Ошибка Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

После отказа носителя восстановил файлы проекта, пытаюсь собрать, выдаёт

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,
>   :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies,
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources,
>   :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
>   Error: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Перерыл много источников, но подходящего ответа не нашёл. Помогите.

Comment: пере-импортировать проект пробовали? *оффтоп* это будет отличным уроком, почему нужно использовать системы контроля версия

Comment: @metalurgus, пере-импорт не помогает, иде отказывается видеть файлы, поэтому создал новый проект и перенёс все файлы .java, .xml, подправил зависимости gradle'a, добавил отсутствующие строки в .imi, после чего попытался собрать проект на что иде выдала мне вышеуказанную ошибку.